# How to wrap nav-item and nav-link in a link_to block

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Hello i am trying to wrappe this html code in a `link_to do` block

```
<li class="nav-item">

<a class="nav-link" href="index.html">

<i class="batch-icon batch-icon-browser-alt"></i>
Dashboard 
</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Are you sure that's what you want? You can't put interactive elements (such as `<a>`) inside an `<a>` (which `link_to` gives you) so you'd be producing invalid HTML. Are you really trying to replace the `<a href="index.html">` with a `link_to` call? That would  give you valid HTML and would match the usual Bootstrap structure.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
<%= link_to(...) do %>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">
      <i class="batch-icon batch-icon-browser-alt"></i>
      Dashboard 
    </a>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

[Here is a link to link_to docs](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to)

Comment: Except now they have invalid HTML, you can't put interactive content (such as `<a>`) inside other interactive content (such as the `<a>` that `link_to` produces).

Answer (score 1):

Hello i finally found a solution using `content_tag` helper

```
    <%= content_tag :li ,class: "nav-item" do%>
        <%=link_to  to_path, class:"nav-link" do%>
        <i class="batch-icon batch-icon-search"></i>
        Dashboard
        <%end%>
    <%end%>
```

Hope it helps someone